# Append div class based on check data on checbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I know this is common to ask, but I'm trying to append data based on my check items on my checkbox table whether it is multiple or one, if the add button is clicked it will append based on the selected data either multiple or one, if the data already added in the view it must not append since it's already there only append those data selected if not exist in the viewed class. Did I miss something?

**How to identify if the clicked data already exist on the view?**

[image]

**This is what I've tried but it doesn't work**

```js
$('#allcb').change(function () {
    $('tbody tr td input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add_data").click(function(){
        var grid = document.getElementById("Table1");
        var message = "Values                 Description\n";
        
        var checkBoxes = grid.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
        
        for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
            if (checkBoxes[i].checked) {
            
                var row = checkBoxes[i].parentNode.parentNode;
                
                $(".whole-div-class")
                 .append('<div class="row whole-div-class" ><div class="col-md-8"><p class="me-3"> '+
                 '<a href="#" class="text-body">' + row.cells[1].innerHTML+'</a></p> '+
                '<span class="me-1">Append data</span>'+
                '<a href="#" class="me-3">'+ row.cells[2].innerHTML +'</a>'+
                '<input type="number" class="form-control form-control-sm w-px-75" value="1" min="1" max="5"/>');
               }
              
        }
 
    }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" id="Table1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <input type="checkbox" id="allcb" name="allcb" />
            </th>
            <th>values</th>
            <td>Description</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="cb1" name="cb1" />
            </td>
            <td>this is value 1</td> 
            <td>this is description 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="cb2" name="cb2" />
            </td>
            <td>this is value 2</td> 
            <td>this is description 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="cb3" name="cb3" />
            </td>
             <td>this is value 3</td> 
            <td>this is description 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<button type="button" id="add_data">Add data</button>

<div class="row whole-div-class" > </div>
```

Comment: I've updated my snippet above but it returns redundant data

Comment: How to identify if the clicked data already exist on the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues that you have in our code.

There is no way to detect whether your input has already been parsed and the output html is created for that particular checkbox

You are appending the contents of elements with class name `"whole-div-class"`, but that content also has an element with class name `"whole-div-class"`. This will create 2 elements with class name `"whole-div-class"` in first run, and later the logic will append the new content to those two nodes. This will work like a chain reaction.

So your appending content should not contain an element with class name `"whole-div-class"`

The logic I followed is simple. I added a custom property to the input called `hasCovered`, which indicates that I have already looped through this input. So next time I will check whether this property is set on that input before appending the new HTML content.

Also I removed the input with name `"allcb"`, because this is not needed for the logic.

**Working code**

```js
$("#allcb").change(function () {
  $('tbody tr td input[type="checkbox"]').prop(
    "checked",
    $(this).prop("checked")
  );
});

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#add_data").click(function () {
    var grid = document.getElementById("Table1");
    var message = "Values                 Description\n";

    var checkBoxes = grid.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
    var str = ''

    for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
      if (
        checkBoxes[i].checked &&
        checkBoxes[i].name !== "allcb" &&
        !checkBoxes[i].hasCovered
      ) {
        var row = checkBoxes[i].parentNode.parentNode;
        str +=
          '<div class="row" ><div class="col-md-8"><p class="me-3"> ' +
          '<a href="#" class="text-body">' +
          row.cells[1].innerHTML +
          "</a></p> " +
          '<span class="me-1">Append data</span>' +
          '<a href="#" class="me-3">' +
          row.cells[2].innerHTML +
          "</a>" +
          '<input type="number" class="form-control form-control-sm w-px-75" value="1" min="1" max="5"/>' +
          "</div></div>";
          checkBoxes[i].hasCovered = true;
        }
      }
      $(".whole-div-class").append(str);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" id="Table1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <input type="checkbox" id="allcb" name="allcb" />
      </th>
      <th>values</th>
      <td>Description</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="cb1" name="cb1" />
      </td>
      <td>this is value 1</td>
      <td>this is description 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="cb2" name="cb2" />
      </td>
      <td>this is value 2</td>
      <td>this is description 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="cb3" name="cb3" />
      </td>
      <td>this is value 3</td>
      <td>this is description 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br />
<button type="button" id="add_data">Add data</button>

<div class="row whole-div-class"></div>
```

Comment: One more thing can I remove the specific list based on selected item through button?

Comment: @marivicvaldehueza Have you tried something for that?

Comment: Thanks for the response not yet I'm still trying to delete each row, but still have an error, I want to put delete button in each item

Comment: Please post the relevant attempt as a new question, since the scope of current question doesnot include that